# How Can I change instance EC2 from Oregon to Virginia

Tags: amazon-web-services

How Can I change instance EC2 from Oregon to Virginia? Is there any form by console? I have one Instance RDS and one Instance EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a snapshot of the RDS instance, and either a snapshot of your EBS volume(s) on EC2, or create an AMI from your EC2 instance.
2. Move the snapshot(s) and AMI to the new region.
3. Create a new RDS instance in the new region using the RDS snapshot you copied there.
4. Create a new EC2 instance in the new region from the AMI or EBS snapshots you copied there.
5. Update your application on your new EC2 instance to point to the new RDS location.
6. Move any DNS entries or Elastic IP addresses to point to the new servers and shut down the old ones.